# How to fix OutOfMemory on Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, imagemap

I'm trying to solve an ImageMap problem in Android. Therefore I wrote a small class which matches the touch coordinates with the previously defined areas. 
Here is the class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (observer != null) {
        if(checkClickArea(event)){
            observer.OnAreaClick(v,event, matchedArea);
        }

    }
    return false;
}

boolean checkClickArea(MotionEvent event){

    Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int displayWidth = size.x;
    int displayHeight = imageView.getHeight();

    int touchImageX = Math.round((imageWidth / displayWidth) * event.getX());
    int touchImageY = Math.round((imageHeight / displayHeight) * event.getY());


    if (arealist != null) {
        for (ImageArea area : arealist) {
            if (area.rectF.contains(touchImageX, touchImageY)) {
                matchedArea = area;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is going to work so far. To mark the clicked areas as "clicked" I put the different images into a [**`LayerDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable) and give them to the Image View.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.kopf));
    drawablesIDs.add(R.drawable.kopf);

    ImageClickRecognizer imageClickRecognizer = new ImageClickRecognizer(getApplicationContext(), ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.kopf)));
    imageClickRecognizer.setImageView(imageView);
    imageClickRecognizer.setOnAreaClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void OnAreaClick(View v, MotionEvent event, ImageClickRecognizer.ImageArea area) {



    final int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(area.shape.name, "drawable",getPackageName());


    if (drawablesIDs.contains(resourceId)){

        drawablesIDs.remove(Integer.valueOf(resourceId));
        updateImageView();

    }else{
        drawablesIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(resourceId));
        updateImageView();

    }
}


private void updateImageView(){
    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[drawablesIDs.size()];

    for (int i=0; i<drawablesIDs.size(); i++){
        Drawable draw = getDrawable(drawablesIDs.get(i));
        draw.setAlpha(150);
        layers[i] = draw;
    }

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

}
```

except for a small delay it also works fine only the problem is, as soon as the twelfth image is loaded into LayerDrawable I get an OOM error. Although the images are 10 kBit pngs.

any ideas why that might be ?

Comment: How big in pixels are your images?

Comment: all images have the size 1265x903

Comment: I cut the image size in half and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you will see [**Android Handling Bitmaps**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics)

This is very common in the case of large Images.

You should use `inSampleSize` to scale your image before putting into `Drawable[]`

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

`calculateInSampleSize` method is picked from [Android Loading Large images efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your manifest file :

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true">

    <activity>
        ...
    </activity>

</application>
```